# Call Excel VB AddIn From Macro

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba

So I'm trying to build a series of data entry forms in Excel that are coded in C# in visual studio.  I'd like to be able to store an entire library of these forms in an add-in, and only show certain forms depending on the excel document that's open.  I know that with a few tricks, the excel ribbon can be customized per individual document,

(ex.)
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

but I've only been able to find ways to run macros from the customized ribbon...  Is there a way to reference a C# Add-In from a macro?  If not, is there a way to reference it from building a custom xml Add-In?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expose the classes and objects of the add-in to be able to use them outside of the add-in in VBA.

Here's a nice tutorial on how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608614.aspx

Comment: Thanks! After hours of searching I wasn't able to find a tutorial like that